# Searching for a .NET SAP RFC tutorial for remote capable SAP modules

Tags: .net, saprfc, sap-dotnet-connector

Is there a tutorial which explains step by step how to connect to a remote capable SAP module?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using .NET connector or Web Services?

Comment: I was thinking that the connector supports both, web services and remote function calls (RFC)? I was planning to use RFC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a tutorial on codeproject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/SAP_NET_RFC_Server.aspx) and a SAP description of the process on [help.sap](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/91/00c47831d3ce4aad5253c1e021e525/frameset.htm)

Hope this help,

regards
Guillaume

Edit : there is also a tutorial [here](http://www.customsoftwarebypreston.com/SAPNetConnector.aspx)

Comment: This answer is obsolete. There is a new SAPConnector in Version 3.